# c++ Inaccessible constructor in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
    class Timp {

    // constructori
    Timp() {
        this->timp_intre_taste = 0;
        this->timp_tasta = 0;
    }

    Timp(int t1, int t2) {
        this->timp_intre_taste = t1;
        this->timp_tasta = t2;
    }
    // getteri and setteri 

    int getTimpIntreTaste(){
        return timp_intre_taste;}
    void setTimpIntreTaste(int timpIntreTaste){
        timp_intre_taste = timpIntreTaste;}

    int getTimpTasta()
    {
        return timp_tasta;
    }
    void setTimpTasta(int timpTasta)
    {
        timp_tasta = timpTasta;
    }

protected:
    int timp_intre_taste;
    int timp_tasta;

};

class Sesiune : public Timp 
{

    int id_utilizator;
    int nr_click_stanga;
    int nr_click_dreapta;

public:
    Sesiune():Timp(0,0)
    {
        this->id_utilizator = 0;
        this->nr_click_dreapta = 0;
        this->nr_click_stanga = 0;
    }
```

And i have these error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>   Error (active)        "Timp::Timp(int t1, int t2)" (declared at line 17) is
>   inaccessible  Project3.0  d:\salv\facultate\visualstudio\Project3.0\Project3.0\Source.cpp 51  16

Comment: You need to make `Timp::Timp()` `protected` or `public`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks :D

Comment: and you may also want the other getters and setters public.Private setters dont make much sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well error says what's happening. Default properties of class is "private", which means that only this class can access this. No other class can access this. You have to change to public (everyone have access) or protected (only this class and derived class have access)

Comment: "Error says what's happening", well... I wasn't here if the error said what's happening